# How do I get data from a POST request on Nancy 2.0?

Tags: c#, rest, post, request, nancy

I need to implement a POST request handler using NancyFX 2.0. As opposed to a GET request, I don't understand how to handle the POST on Nancy 2.0, as there isn't any data on the url nor in the parameters variable.

My code is currently as follows:

My NancyModule Post method:

```
Post("/add/{firstname:string}", parameters => AddAction(parameters));
```

AddAction Method:

```
dynamic AddAction(dynamic parameters)
   {
    //I would need to print the JSON or bind it into a Client object here
   }
```

And this is my Client class:

```
public Client(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string address)
   {
       ID = id; 
       FirstName = firstName;
       LastName = lastName;
       Address = address;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model bind like this in your handler: `var c = this.Bind<Client>();`.

Here is the documentation: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Model-binding

Comment: This was it! An important note, if somebody can't make it work like me, in the POST request, check the JSON keys in the body are exactly the same as the model's attributes, as the binding is case sensitive.